# How to fetch the image of a music artist from internet for a music app?

Tags: android, http

I am developing a music player for android which will display the wallpaper of the artists whose song is being played,in the background.Instead of searching for the proper service on internet or setting up my  own service,i can search the Google and return the first results or random results. i can search the URL with HTTP post,but dunno how to fetch the URL of the first or any other image,can anyone tell me how i can achieve that? any code or link or documentation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google WebSearch API. Especially querying for images will be interesting for you which works like that:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=Beatles
```

As the result, you will get simple Json, which you will have to parse to get the first image.

Please note that Google has deprecated this API. It still works, but the number of allowed queries is limited. Google recommends using the newer custom search API, which is restricted to 100 free queries. (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more??i know nothing about JSON

Comment: There is information in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html. Additionally, Google will help you with finding tutorials.